# There is not stories tab in wit.ai

Tags: artificial-intelligence, wit.ai

I am trying to build a chatbot using [wit.ai](https://wit.ai). I have managed to make **intent** and their **values** with different **questions** but i am unable to understand that **where to put answer of every intent**. I mean how to form a dialogue or conversation system as there is not **stories tab**in current wit.ai.

**I saw different Tuts where stories tab (in beta format) available (to make dialogue) but in current site it is not available.**

Answer (score 1):

The stories feature has been deprecated.

More information [here](https://wit.ai/blog/2017/07/27/sunsetting-stories).

If you want something similar, maybe have a look at [api.ai](http://api.ai)

Comment: I have checked but how do i make dialogue system

Comment: If you are using a wit.ai then your bot will need to handle all the responses based on the users intent. If using api.ai, the intent section has an area for your dialogue/replies.